# Ubuntu 11.10 will only start in restore mode

Tags: 11.10, restore

I have Ubuntu 11.10, with gnome, running on a Dell Inspiron 620.

It was running fine until the power company came around and turned off the power to change a meter.  Now, when I try to boot it up, it will only start in restore mode.  I tried

```
Check all file systems
```

and it reported that it had fixed the hardware clock.  I then ran

Repair broken packages

and it ran to completion but it still will not start in graphics mode.  Whe I try to start it up in normal mode, the screen just remains black.

When the terminal started up in restore mode, I entered

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

That got stuck on

```
Stopping Userspace bootsplash
```

I tried to fix this with the following procedure

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a

reboot
```

I went into recovery mode again and entered

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

It failed on:
- Stopping automatic crash report generation
- Starting deferred execution scheduler
- starting save kernel messages
- Starting load fallback graphics devices

This time it did get past "Stopping Userspace bootsplash"

Now it hangs on

```
Starting CUPS printing spooler/server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem.  Got the restore mode terminal and entered

```
sudo service gdm start
```

This brought up Gnome which I much prefer to Unity.